# Migrating from manually managed HttpClient (with separate TokenUri) to IHttpClientFactory

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient, .net-core-3.1

I have got an web application that lacks to free memory.
I suspect HttpClient to be one of the issues, because the object count of HttpClient is increasing over time.

Therefore I want to migrate to the managed IHttpClientFactory, but now I'm stuck with how to best implement the call to the token service (I thought about using the [typed client variant](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.1#typed-clients)).

Right now it's implemented this way:

```
var myClient = new MyClient(credentials, baseUri, tokenUri, timeout);
```

Inside of MyClient HttpClient(1) takes care of calling the token service (credentials, tokenUri), storing the expiry date and returning the bearer token to HttpClient(2) that calls the endpoint (baseUri, timeout). 
If myClient now tries to fetch some data, it checks if the token needs to be refreshed, if not it fetches the data.

How would I do this with IHttpClientFactory? 
 Do I still need to handle HttpClient(1) myself (expiry date) or will the factory somehow detect if it needs to refresh the token or not? 
I at least understood, that the factory decides if a connection stays open or not.

Comment: You're most likely on the right track in trying to transition to HttpClientFactory to help manage your handler pool, but we may need a bit more information on the client implementation. Is there just one set of credentials and a token being managed, or multiple across different users/contexts? Is the token lifespan short or long? Can you share a few more details around where and how the clients are being created and their lifespan?

Comment: @AdamG There are two clients with different credentials, so I guess I'd need two typed clients. They aren't user/context dependent. The token lifespan is 1 hour. The clients are created just once (new MyClient) in my webservice proxy and kept until the program ends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're on the right track with the transition to HttpClientFactory, and particularly a typed HttpClient.

Under the hood, HttpClientFactory's default implementation manages the pooling and disposal of the underlying primary message handler, which means that the actual HttpClient sitting on top of it can start being generated and disposed in a scoped fashion rather than trying to manage some global, long-running instance of it or creating and tearing down one-off instances, which is well described in Microsoft's own documentation: [Use IHttpClientFactory to implement resilient HTTP requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests)

In cases like yours where the HttpClient was potentially long-lived, it may have made sense for the client itself to manage state within its instance (such as the token), but you end up needing to take  a different path now that the client can (and should) be disposed of more frequently.

***Do I still need to handle HttpClient(1) myself (expiry date) or will the factory somehow detect if it needs to refresh the token or not?***

Yes you still need to handle it, but the HttpClientFactory pattern gives you some tools to help manage it. Since you're inherently leaning into dependency injection with the use of HttpClientFactory, there's a couple different paths you might go.

At the most basic would be just to add some sort of singleton token provider that manages the tokens for you and can be injected into the typed client by the DI container:

```
public interface ITokenProvider
{
    string GetToken(string key);
    void StoreToken(string key, string token);
}

// Incredibly basic example, not thread safe, etc...
public class InMemoryTokenProvider : ITokenProvider
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, string> _tokenList = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public string GetToken(string key)
    {
        return _tokenList.GetValueOrDefault(key);
    }

    public void StoreToken(string key, string token)
    {
        _tokenList.Remove(key); // upsert, you get the point...
        _tokenList.Add(key, token);
    }
}

public class TypedClient
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;
    private readonly ITokenProvider _tokenProvider;

    public TypedClient(HttpClient client, ITokenProvider tokenProvider)
    {
        _client = client;
        _tokenProvider = tokenProvider;
    }

    public async Task DoYourThing()
    {
        var token = _tokenProvider.GetToken("token_A");
        // ... if it failed, then UpdateTheAuth()
    }

    private async Task UpdateTheAuth()
    {
        var result = await _client.GetAsync("the auth process");
        string token = "whatever";
        // ...
        _tokenProvider.StoreToken("token_A", token);
    }
}
```

When you do your service registration at the start and register the token provider as a singleton, all your state (such as the token) is no longer part of the client itself, so your client can now be disposed and injected wherever. That provider could also be written off to a cache or a database, too.

This can still be a little clunky because its still putting all the logic for calling, failing, updating auth, retrying, etc. within your typed client logic -- it might be good enough if that covers what you need, or you may want something more robust. HttpClientFactory makes it easy to add a delegating handler pipeline as well as [policies for resiliency with Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Polly-and-HttpClientFactory), such as retry:

```
services.AddTransient<ExampleDelegatingHandler>();
services.AddHttpClient<IMyHttpClient, MyHttpClient>()
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<TokenApplicationHandler>()
    .AddPolicyHandler(GetRetryPolicy()); // see Microsoft link
```

The delegating handler pipeline attaches to your typed client and runs like middleware for every request and response (and can modify them in flight), so you could even move some of this token management off into a delegating handler instead:

```
public class TokenApplicationHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly ITokenProvider _tokenProvider;
    private readonly IAuthRenewerClient _authRenewer;

    public TokenApplicationHandler(ITokenProvider tokenProvider, IAuthRenewerClient authRenewer)
    {
        _tokenProvider = tokenProvider;
        _authRenewer = authRenewer;
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // All just demo level, take the implementation with a grain of salt...
        string token = _tokenProvider.GetToken("token_A");
        request.Headers.Add("x-token-header", token);

        var response =  await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode && response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
        {
            string newToken = _authRenewer.RefreshAuth();
            _tokenProvider.StoreToken("token_A", newToken);
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

Paired with a retry policy, now any time a request goes out and comes back with an `Unauthorized` response, your delegating handler can handle the renewal and then the request gets resent the new token, and your typed HttpClient doesn't need to be any the wiser (or even necessarily deal with auth at all).

Key takeaways, make sure as you transition to this pattern that you're disposing of the clients you're creating when you're done with whatever scope they're in so HttpClientFactory can do its background magic.

Comment: I didn't specifically add it in my response since its an external link, but there's also ways to cover the token refresh as part of the Polly policy directly: https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/refresh-google-access-token-with-polly/

Comment: I don't understand how the token provider handles http-requests in your first example. As far as I understand you propose, that the typed client handles it, but I can't use the same httpClient for it, as there are two different Uris for authentication and fetching data - and that's the main point where I'm stuck (because you can't reset BaseAddress of HttpClient). Do I need to provide another HttpClient via DI? Normally I'd like InMemoryTokenProvider to do the job: on GetToken it checks if it's expired and refreshes it if necessary, but therefore it needs a HttpClient.

Comment: Is it possible that InMemoryTokenProvider gets HttpClient injected in its constructor and that InMemoryTokenProvider itself is injected into the TypedClient?

Comment: To your point, the token provider does not perform requests, it just persists the tokens so that your typed client becomes less stateful and can be disposed and recreated as needed to take advantage of HttpClientFactory benefits. Since you're abstracting the HttpClient access, you might skip setting the base address and construct the absolute URL at request time, have two completely separate typed clients with dedicated behavior (still stateless, since there's a shared cache), put the auth work into a Polly policy directly, or offload that client and auth into the delegating handler pipeline.